# QWebPage / QPrinter - can't load page

Tags: c++, qt, qwebpage, qprinter

I am new in Qt and I need to do a program who export html page to PDF

So, the main idea is use `QWebPage` for interpret html and export itself to pdf with `QPrinter`.

I have two class `webview` who use `QWebPage` and `Print` who use `QPrinter`.

In `main.cpp` I have connect `LoadFinished` to `PrintPDF` slot:

```
Print *pdf = new Print(args);
webview *nav = new webview();
nav->setPrinter(pdf->getPrinter());

if(nav->load(args) == false) {
    qDebug() << "can't load page";
    return 0;
}
//when the page page is ready, we will print it
QObject::connect(nav->getFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), nav, SLOT(printPDF(bool)));
```

My `webview.cpp` class:

```
#include "webview.h"
webview::webview()
{
    page = new QWebPage;
    printer = 0;
}

webview::~webview()
{
    delete page;
}

bool webview::load(Arguments *args)
{
    QRegularExpression url("^(file|http)://");
    QRegularExpression fullPath("^/");

    QRegularExpressionMatch pathMatch = fullPath.match(args->getSource());
    QRegularExpressionMatch urlMatch = url.match(args->getSource());

    // see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebsettings.html#WebAttribute-enum for more informations
    page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::LocalStorageEnabled, true);
    page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::AutoLoadImages, true);
    page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
    page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PrintElementBackgrounds, true);
    page->settings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::PluginsEnabled, true);

    if(pathMatch.hasMatch()) {
        page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(args->getSource()));
    } else {
        if (urlMatch.hasMatch()) {
            page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl(args->getSource()));
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", qPrintable(QApplication::translate("main", "Error: Invalide source file")));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void webview::printPDF(bool ok)
{
    if(ok == true) {
        qDebug() << "okay";
    } else
        qDebug() << "non okay";
    if(printer != 0)
        page->mainFrame()->print(printer);
}
```

This is what my console display:

> non okay 
>   QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time.

I have no idea where the error might be due. The whole project is [here](http://paf.im/9zSsL)

The arguments are:

```
./htmltopdf http://stackoverflow.com destinationFolder
```

(destinationFolder is not yet implemented, you must directly modify the source code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was elsewhere :

In my `main.cpp` I had this :

```
QObject::connect(nav->getFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), nav, SLOT(printPDF(bool)));
[...]
delete args;
delete pdf;
delete nav;

return app.exec();
```

`app.exec()` is a kind of infinit loop who thaht handles Qt events  and thus allows the program does not close. 
If I proceed to delete before calling this function,then I will have freshly deallocated pointers that will be used

If I Do :

```
bool result = app.exec();

delete args;
delete pdf;
delete nav;

return result;
```

It's work fine !

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one Painter in your Code. Search for it.
I thing the Problem is in your "Printer Class". With a Local Printer in the printPDF Method it works. Try it:

```
void webview::printPDF(bool ok)
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Export PDF",
        QString(), "*.pdf");

    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);
    page()->mainFrame()->print(&printer);
}
```

**UPDATE: Here a small working Example:**

***testview.cpp***

```
#include "testview.h"
#include <QWebFrame>
#include "webview.h"
#include <QWebPage>
#include <QGridLayout>
testview::testview(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    QGridLayout* Layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    webview* w = new webview(this);
    w->setMinimumSize(500, 500);

    centralWidget()->setLayout(Layout);
    bool a = connect(w->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), w, SLOT(printPDF(bool)));
    w->page()->mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"));
}

testview::~testview()
{

}
```

***webview.cpp***

```
#include "webview.h"
#include <QPrinter>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QFileDialog>
webview::webview(QWidget *parent)
    : QWebView(parent)
{

}

webview::~webview()
{

}

void webview::printPDF(bool ok)
{
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, "Export PDF",
        QString(), "*.pdf");

    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setOrientation(QPrinter::Portrait);
    printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
    printer.setOutputFileName(fileName);
    page()->mainFrame()->print(&printer);
}
```

Comment: You're right, the message " QPainter::begin: A paint device can only be painted by one painter at a time." no longer appears.
The boolean send is always at "false" and the page has been printed is a blank page

Comment: Check the path in         page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile(args->getSource()));
and
page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl(args->getSource())); is it a valid path? Use the load function of the webview:   connect(webview->page()->mainFrame(), SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), webview, SLOT(printPDF(bool)));
webview->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("c:/test.html"));

Comment: Yes is a valid path (and i am sur). 
I have replace :  page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl(args->getSource()));
 by 
page->mainFrame()->load(QUrl("http://stackoverflow.com"));
And the problem remains the same.
The boolean sent to printPDF stay false

Comment: you use your own webpage. Do you call WebView::setPage() to set your page in the webview? The name page is not a good choice, because there is a Method page() in the webview to get the current page. Rename your page, set your Page with setPage() and then you can get your page in the connect with getPage();

Comment: Thank you very much  for you're help !But the problem was elsewhere. I will answser soon for more details!